# How to share data between webapp users over GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore

I have a webapp deployed on GAE and users can sign-in using OpenID. Once users are signed-in they can access the data store for their own data.

Now, if I want to establish a "shared data space", how can I achieve such a thing? Can I give access to user A to data from user B? We share entities? How can I overcome access restrictions?

Any help on this aspect will be greatly appreciated.

---

### EDIT 1

Not quite the BigTable expert. I'm not looking for magical kingdom solution, just pointer on how to tackle this problem (blog, article, tutorial, etc).

But if I get it right, data is accessible by anyone with access to the application (if access control is available). So if I give the a {KEY, entity} pair to user B from user A he will be able to access it no problem?

Maybe I'm just confusing concepts...

Comment: This question is too general to answer. There are no built-in user-specific restrictions on data access - data belongs to the app, not a user - so you must have built those yourself. In which case, only you know how to use them to share data.

Comment: Thanks Roseman, I edited a bit to better explain myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAE datastore is a database. Data stored in it is in no way restricted to a single user. BTW, you don't even have to sign in to use a GAE application. Just query for the data you want, and you'll get it, whether the current user stored it or anyone else is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, so I could start asking for random data by querying the datastore? Nothing is securing data access? This is strange, on RDBMS there is at least a user restriction to avoid anyone accessing the database.

Comment: No, it's the same thing on a RDBMS. Data inserted in a table by a given user is visible by all the users (unless the table itself is unreadable). And in most of the apps, a single database user is used to insert everything. Do you think Amazon declares all its end users as database users?

Comment: I was mixing the webapp user and the database user... a registered GAE application has access to the datastore, but not everyone in the universe has? DB user has to supply credentials to the database (say Postgres) otherwise access is denied.

Comment: You don't have to provide any credentials, because due to the design of the datastore, a webapp is owned by only has one GAE account, and this datastore is accessible only by this unique GAE account.